# copy a xml document with attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to copy a xml document complete with attributes and nodes.  The output does not contain attributes. fi.xml is the input, test.xsl does the transform (a mode is required in xsl).  Thanks.

```
f1.xml
<test attr="val">
  <subtest attr2="val2"/>
</test>

test.xsl
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('f1.xml')" mode="abc"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()" mode="abc">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="abc"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>
  <subtest/>
</test>
```

Comment: bretter: You may be interested in two solutions that are simpler and more standard than the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That stylesheet seems very odd, but try changing your `xsl:apply-templates` to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="abc" select="@*|node()"/>
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. apply-templates without a select is supposed to process all children of current node.  Oh well, live and learn.

Answer (score 4):

**The shortest solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('f1.xml')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**A more flexible solution, but simpler (no modes) and more standard**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "document('f1.xml')/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate application of the [**identity rule**](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) on the children of the document-node of `document('f1.xml')`

Comment: @DevNull: You are welcome. You did a good job finding and explaining the issue, +1.